# ES6 - call anonymous generator with the arrow syntax

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How I can call generator like this:

```
const scenarioProvider = (function*() {
    ....
}).bind(this)();
```

By the arrow function syntax. I mean to replace the 'bind(this)' by the new 'lexical this'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible and is not likely to be included in future versions of ecmascript.

> Just to let everyone know (meeting notes, coming soon, will make this clear), we agreed not to do generator arrows. Too much trouble of the kind identified here...

source: [Brendan Eich @esdiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions#content-37)

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions by definition are lexically scoped. You cannot [use a generator with an arrow function](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions)

Note however than you cannot bind an arrorw function.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) states:

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to bind that i just want to remove 'bind' and use the lexical this instead.

Comment: Like I said, it's lexical by default, no binding necessary

Comment: With a generator, not possible